# jqGrid loses edits when you reorder or filter

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that has the following properties;

```
    grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: GRID.GridData,
        colModel: GRID.availableGridColumns['columnModel'],
        loadonce: true,
```

It loads the data just fine.

I then make an inline edit to one to the cells.

I then apply a filter, or a sort, and the edit I made to the cell is now gone and the value is back to its original value.

I also have this;

```
    var rowData = $('#Grid').jqGrid('getRowData', "11332601");
    rodData.State = "Open";
    $('#Grid').setRowData("11332601", rowData)
```

The value in the cell is changed but when I apply a filter or a sort, the cell value is changed back to its original value.

This can also be demonstrated here http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html and then opening "New in version 3.3" and selecting the "Cell Editing" link.

Sort the grid by "Amount", change the value of "50.00" to be say "51.00".  Sort by amount again and then again and you will see that "51.00" has changed back to "50.00".

Is there a workaround for this behavior?